# Excel VBA sort bug

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I've been writing macros in Excel VBA for the last couple weeks (mostly successfully) for my internship and have come to bug. Here's the code that I believe has the bug (which usually generates this error: "Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error").

I wish I could show the data I'm working with to give more context but it's confidential employee data. What you need to know is that the goal of this code is to alphabetically sort employee names.

```
'Establish where names are contained in data
startLetter = InputBox("Please enter the letter of the first column that contains the employee names:", "Where Names Start")
endLetter = InputBox("Please enter the letter of the last column that contains the employee names:", "Where Names End")
startNames = source.Range(startLetter & 1).Column
endNames = source.Range(endLetter & 1).Column

source.Range(source.Cells(rowStart, startNames), source.Cells(rowEnd, endNames)).Select
source.Sort.SortFields.Clear
source.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=source.Range(source.Cells(rowStart,  startNames) _    <---error line
    ), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With source.Sort
    .SetRange source.Range(source.Cells(rowStart, startNames), source.Cells(rowEnd, endNames))
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51368843/edit) your question with the actual code, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Also add the data on which you are using the code, before, after and what do you expect.

Comment: If you can't share the actual data, replace it with a small dummy data set that produces the same error and share that instead.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to your module at the top. If nothing else, it will help the complier provide more meaningful error messages earlier.

Comment: Maybe also change `...SortFields.Add2` to [`SortFields.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sortfields-add-method-excel) - should eliminate compatibility issues with other versions of Excel.

Comment: @BigBen I changed it to SortFields.Add and the error changed to "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set." Any thoughts on the new error?

Comment: Hmm - are you sure `rowStart` and `startNames` are what you expect? What are their values if you `Debug.Print` them? What line throws the error?

Comment: I just added some code to what I had above, as you can see the error now occurs there.

Comment: Scratch that, I just reset my data and the sub ran until the now updated error line, at which it gave me the generic '400' error (when I debugged further it gave me the '1004' error)

Comment: `Key:=source.Range(source.Cells(rowStart, startNames)...` - if the key is a single cell, you shouldn't have `source.Range` - just refer to `source.Cells(rowStart, startNames)`.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Key:=source.Range(source.Cells(rowStart, startNames)...` - You shouldn't have `source.Range` here - your key is the single cell `source.Cells(rowStart, startNames)`.
2. As a recommendation - change `...SortFields.Add2` to [`...SortFields.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sortfields-add-method-excel). The `..Add2` will definitely not work in older versions of Excel.